# Proof equivalence of $f:V \rightarrow W$ is a homomorphism and there exists $f_1,...,f_n \in V^{*}$ with $f(v)=f_1(v)b_1+...+f_n(v)b_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof equivalence of

> $f:V \rightarrow W$ is a homomorphism
> $\iff$ there exists $f_1,...,f_n \in V^{*}$ with $f(v)=f_1(v)b_1+...+f_n(v)b_n$

where $V^{*}$ is the dual space and $b_1,...,b_n$ is a basis of $W$.

Does anyone have any hints how to proof this?

Comment: *Hint*: What does the dual basis of $b_1,\dots,b_n$ do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and that dim($W)<\infty$.
Suppose that $f$ is linear (i.e., homomorphic). Let $(b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n})$
be an ordered base for $W$. For each $v\in V$, since $f(v)\in W$,
there exist uniquely $\alpha_{1}(v),\ldots,\alpha_{n}(v)\in K$ (where
$K=\mathbb{R}$ or $K=\mathbb{C}$) such that $f(v)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}(v)b_{i}$.
Define a map $f_{i}:V\rightarrow K$ by $f_{i}(v)=\alpha_{i}(v)$.
Since $\alpha_{1}(v),\ldots,\alpha_{n}(v)$ are uniquely determined
by $v$, $f_{i}$ is well-defined.

It is routine to check that $f_{i}$ is linear and hence $f_{i}\in V^{\ast}$.
For, let $u,v\in V$. Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(u+v) & = & f(u)+f(v)\\
 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}(u)b_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}(v)b_{i}\\
 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\alpha_{i}(u_{i})+\alpha_{i}(v_{i})]b_{i}.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, $f(u+v)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}(u+v)b_{i}$. Since
$(b_{1},\ldots,b_{n})$ is an ordered base, the representation is unique and hence we have that $\alpha_{i}(u+v)=\alpha_{i}(u)+\alpha_{i}(v)$.
Therefore, $f_{i}(u+v)=f_{i}(u)+f_{i}(v)$. Similarly, we can prove
that $f_{i}(\beta v)=\beta f_{i}(v)$ for any $\beta\in K$ and $v\in V$.

The converse is easy and is just a routine verification.