# Show that $f: V \to W$ is a Homomorphism. $\iff$ There exist $f_1, ..., f_n \in V^{*}$ with $f(v) = f(v)_1b_1 + ... + f(v)_nb_n$ for all $v \in V$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, group-homomorphism

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $K$ and $b_1, ..., b_n$ a Basis of $W$. Show for all map $f: V \to W$ those are equivalent:

(i) $f: V \to W$ is a Homomorphism.

(ii) There exist $f_1, ..., f_n \in V^{*}$ with $f(v) = f(v)_1b_1 + ... + f(v)_nb_n$ for all $v \in V$

---

(i) $\implies$ (ii)

Homomorphism means $f(\alpha v + \beta u) = \alpha f(v) + \beta f(u)$

If $b_1, ..., b_n$ are a basis of $W$, and knowing that $f: V \to W$, that means we can write each $f = \alpha_1b_1 + ... + \alpha_nb_n$

To complete the proof, we must somehow have $\alpha_1 = f(v)_1, ..., \alpha_n = f(v)_n$, is that correct ? If yes, how would that work ?

---

(i) $\impliedby$ (ii)

Let's assume that $f(v) = f(v)_1b_1 + ... + f(v)_nb_n$

If we have $f(\alpha v + \beta u) = f_1(\alpha v + \beta u)b_1 + ... + f_n(\alpha v + \beta u)b_n$

If we can somehow split up
$$(\alpha f_1(v) + \beta f_1(u))b_1 + ... +  (\alpha f_n(v) + \beta f_n(u))b_n = $$
$$\alpha (f_1(v)b_1 + ... + f_n(v)b_n) + \beta (f_1(v)b_1 + ... + f_n(v)b_n) = $$
$$\alpha f(v) + \beta f(u) $$
which shows it is a Homomorphism, but are we allowed to do that ?

---

This question did not help me
[Proof equivalence of $f:V \rightarrow W$ is a homomorphism and there exists $f_1,...,f_n \in V^{*}$ with $f(v)=f_1(v)b_1+...+f_n(v)b_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297940/proof-equivalence-of-fv-rightarrow-w-is-a-homomorphism-and-there-exists-f-1)

Comment: Apart from the notational ambiguity already noted, $f = \alpha_1b_1 + ... + \alpha_nb_n$ makes no sense.

Comment: @blargoner Why ? What else should I write ? My idea was that because there is a basis $b_i$ in $W$, so the destination set of $f$, we can write every $f$ using the basis, isn't that the case ?

Comment: Because $f$ is not a vector in $W$.

Comment: @blargoner So what should be changed ? Is there a way to rewrite it to be correct ?

Comment: The person who answered already showed the correct type of thing to write. You could also write $f=f_1\otimes b_1+\cdots+f_n\otimes b_n$ if you know about tensor products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation are ambigus... I guess that you mean : there are $f_1,...,f_n\in V^*$ s.t. $f(v)=f_1(v)b_1+...+f_n(v)b_n$.

---

- For $(i)\implies (ii)$ it's indeed the idea.

Let $V=Span\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ where $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis. For $v\in V$, define $\alpha _i: V\to \mathbb R$ by $$v=\alpha _1(v)v_1+...+\alpha _n(v)v_n.$$

Then, you can easily show that $\alpha _i\in V^*$, and thus, taking $f_i=\alpha _i$ allows you to conclude.

- For the converse, what you did is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much ! What exactly was ambiguous in the notation ?

Comment: $f(v)_i$ whould be the i-th component of the vector $f(v)$, whereas $f_i'$s are function that are a priori different from $f(v)_i$ (in this case however, indeed, both "match" but you're doing things backwards)